# ReactJs Tree Chart with X,Y Axis

Tags: reactjs, charts, tree

Does anyone know of a chart component like this for reactjs?

https://plotly.com/python/tree-plots

Tree Chart

[image: Tree Chart]

Comment: Already solved using this solution : https://stackoverflow.com/a/43416070/6016422

Answer (score 0):

What about `react-d3-tree`?

NPM link: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-d3-tree

Demo link: https://bkrem.github.io/react-d3-tree-demo/

Set the demo to vertical, so it looks like your example.

Comment: Thanks for your answer,
I already know these components, but what I need is a tree chart with axes (x, y)